# How to run main statement and else statement only once, inside loop?

Tags: c++, loops

So I'm trying to add controller support to an old game, but am having some trouble with the logic. I need to execute a command once a trigger is pressed, one time. Otherwise I need to execute a command one time if the trigger is released. All inside a while loop, I know I'm missing something obvious. I'm having trouble only sending the -attack command once.

```
while (true) {

  Sleep(100);

  bool flag = false;

  if ((gamepad.rightTrigger == 1) && (flag == false)) 
  {
    SendCommandToConsole(0, 0, "+attack");
    flag = true;
  } 

  else if ((gamepad.rightTrigger == 0) && (flag == true)) 

  {
    SendCommandToConsole(0, 0, "-attack");
  }

}
```

Comment: Declare bool flag *outside* the loop

Comment: A local variable is defined where it occurs in a block scope (`{ }`) and ends its existence with the end of this scope. This is in fact for any scope - even those which are used to group body statements of `for`/`while`/`if`/`else`. You even can define nested scopes without any of them just to control the life-time of locals defined inside of it (something which I use sometimes in combination with [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)). TL;DR: Your definition of `bool flag = false;` is repeated in every iteration of `while (true)`.

Comment: O.T.: `flag == false` -> `!flag` and `flag == true` -> `flag`. Furthermore: `while (true)` -> `for (;;)` (is IMHO more idiomatic).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `if ((gamepad.rightTrigger == 1) && (flag == false))` can be written without the extra parentheses: `if (gamepad.rightTrigger == 1 && flag == false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you my proposal:

```
bool flag = false;
while (true) {
  Sleep(100);

  if ((gamepad.rightTrigger == 1) && (!flag)) 
  {
    SendCommandToConsole(0, 0, "+attack");
    flag = true;
  } 
  else if ((gamepad.rightTrigger == 0) && flag) 
  {
    SendCommandToConsole(0, 0, "-attack");
  }
}
```

You see three things:

- `flag` is declared outside of the `while`-loop, which has been proposed before and which is the answer to your question.
- Don't check for `flag == true` or `flag == false`, just for `flag` or `!flag`, this improves the readability of your code.
- I removed some obsolete empty lines. It's ok to leave an empty line between different parts of your source code, but it's advised to keep `if`-, `then`-, `else`-loops together, also for readability purposes.